# Why doesn't this Python 3 for loop change every variable to 4?

Tags: loops, python-3.x, for-loop

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(list)
for each in list:
    list[each] = 4
print(list)
```

And I get the result:

```
[1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
```

Line 4 seems to be setting "each" to 4 somehow...but I have no idea how. It's SUPPOSED to change the value at the current iterator to 4., which it also does at list[4].

Edit:
Wait wait wait, okay, 'each' is literally coming from the value inside the list? That's the only logical way this any sense, now that I think about it.

Comment: fyi, you should never call something `list` - that shadows the builtin `list()` function.

Comment: Read the python docs on how iterating lists works in Python. You get the items, not the indexes (since the indexes are useless more often than not). Actually, if you only need to iterate over the indexes, you could do `for i in range(len(list))`. But to actually replace all items in the list with a single one, you could simply create a new one: `list = [4] * len(list)`

Comment: oh jesus I wish reading the docs made sense to me even half the time
but still, after figuring out what you mean by items and not indexes; why on earth would you make a language do that?

Comment: actually TheifMaster could you post that as an answer? That's probably the best I'm gonna get.

Comment: If you put `print(each, list)` inside the loop, it might become clearer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work better.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for each in range(len(list)):
    list[each] = 4
print(list)
```

The problem you are running into is that your loop goes over the numbers from 1 - 5, but the index of the list starts at zero.

Adding a zero element to your list, or decrementing the each value by one in the loop makes your code work. But this way of doing it is flawed as you are depending on the content of the list to be in order and represent the positions.

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5] # zero added here.
for each in list:
    list[each] = 4
print(list)
```

Your loop is actually doing this.

```
Loop 1: -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            ^
position 1 = 4.
Output: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]

Loop 2: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
               ^
position 4 = 4.
Output: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]

Loop 3: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
                  ^
position 3 = 4. (it is already 4)
Output: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]

Loop 4: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
                     ^
position 4 = 4. (it is already 4)
Output: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]

Loop 5: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
                        ^
position 4 = 4. (it is already 4)
Output: -> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: ...this Python class I bought doesn't explain what the 'each' does at all

I thought it was just automagically doing the (i = 0, i < x, i++) equivalent of c++

Comment: Very nice step-by-step explanation, showing why `some_list[5]=` does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

Better use `enumerate()`, so you can skip the `range(len())`:

```py
some_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i, item in enumerate(some_list):
    some_list[i] = 4
print(some_list)

[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

This will change each item in `some_list` to `4` by its index.

#### Why your way doesn't work

The thinking error you probably make it that the first item in a list has index 0, not 1 :)
"doing it your way" would then be:

```py
some_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(some_list)
for each in some_list:
    some_list[each-1] = 4
print(some_list)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

#### EDIT

Another way to show what @JensB is explaining is to run the code below. It is exactly showing what happens in each of the iterations:

```py
some_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(some_list)
for each in some_list:
    some_list[each] = 4
    print("some_list["+str(each)+"] = 4")
    print(some_list)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
some_list[1] = 4
[1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
some_list[4] = 4
[1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
some_list[3] = 4
[1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
some_list[4] = 4
[1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
some_list[4] = 4
[1, 4, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over a list, you get the actual items, not the indexes (since the indexes are useless more often than not).

Actually, if you only need to iterate over the indexes, you could do it like this:

```
for i in range(len(your_list))
```

But to actually replace all items in the list with a single one, you could simply create a new one:

```
your_list = [4] * len(your_list)
```

Or if you prefer modifying the existing list:

```
your_list[:] = [4] * len(your_list)
```

Also, you should not name any variable `list`. This shadows the builtin `list()` function which is quite useful e.g. if you want to turn an iterable in a list (with `list` being shadowed you'd have to use `[x for x in iterable]` instead of `list(iterable)`).